# How to Safely Access Property of Object

Tags: c#, winforms, events, dynamic, reflection

I have a WinForms app with several menu item commands that map to the same handler. I use the menu items' `Tag` property to identify how the handler should behave.

The problem is, the handler's `sender` parameter is of type `object`. So how do I read the `Tag` property of an object?

I know I can typecast `sender` to the type of my menu item, but what if I then want a button or other control to map to the same handler? Is there a generic way to read the `Tag` property from whatever object is the sender?

Here's what I have so far. It seems to work. But isn't there a more streamlined way?

```
private void Header_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic ctrl = sender as dynamic;
    if (ctrl != null && sender.GetType().GetProperty("Tag") != null)
    {
        // Go ahead and reference ctrl.Tag
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast is as the parent type of all controls rather than the specific child.

```
Control ctrl = sender as Control;
if (ctrl != null)
    MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Tag.ToString());
```

Comment: That's what I thought. But apparently menu items don't derive from `Control`.

Comment: @Jonathan then try a few things via `as` - or if you are sure it has a .Tag, you could cast it to `dynamic`

Comment: @MarcGravell: I thought I was casting it to `dynamic`.

Comment: @JonathanWood If MenuItem is one of the few controls on your form that doesn't inherit from `Control` then you could perform explicit checks for it since it's an anomaly. Alternatively, as you're looking for a safe method, you could remove your `sender.GetType().GetProperty("Tag") != null` and simply call `sender.Tag` within a `Try...Catch` block. It's likely to be exceptional that a UI object is clicked but doesn't have a `Tag` property.

Comment: @Jonathan basically, what keyboardP said. There is no point casting to dynamic but then using reflection. Cast it to dynamic and then just *access .Tag*

Comment: @keyboardP: To be honest, I don't know how many WinForms controls don't inherit from `Control`. I was very surprised to find that this one didn't. The `Tag` property in both classes is just not from a common base class. Go figure.

Comment: @JonathanWood - I was quite surprised too. I was looking up the tree and it seems that it's a separate implementation as `ComponentModel` doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you are listening to will always have a `.Tag`, then you might as well duck-type:

```
dynamic ctrl = sender;
object tag = ctrl.Tag;
```

Using reflection (like in the question) defeats any point in using `dynamic`.

Comment: That's basically what my code does. The only difference is the reflection check to guard against an exception if the object doesn't support a `Tag` property.